# Ask one property of conditional independence

Tags: probability, statistics

One property of the conditional independence relation is

if $X\perp\kern-5pt\perp Y \mid Z$ and  $X\perp\kern-5pt\perp Z \mid Y$ then  $X\perp\kern-5pt\perp (Y , Z)$.

However the above does not hold universally, but only under additional conditions - essentially that there be no non-trivial logical relationship between Y and Z. A trivial counterexample appears when $X=Y=Z$ with $P(X=1)=P(X=0)=1/2$.

Can anyone explain this counterexample? I don't know how to see this example violates the above relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $X$ is not a constant. Given $Z$, $X$ and $Y$ are constants and constants are independent. So $X\perp\kern-5pt\perp Y \mid Z$. Similary,  $X\perp\kern-5pt\perp Z \mid Y$. But $X$ is not independent of itself (becasue it is not a constant) so $X$ is not independent of $Y$ and $Z$.

Comment: How to interpret "X is not independent of itself?"

Comment: A randon variable is independent of itself if and only if it is a constant. @SofiaDelacruz